# How to stretch vertical div element to fill parent container?

Tags: html, css

I have the following [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/IJInOhA/1/edit)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell">Top left</div>
    <div class="cell">Top left bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell">Center</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell">Top right</div>
    <div class="cell">Top right bottom</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make vertical aligned divs **without explicit setting of height** and position to absolute to look like the following:

**EDIT:** Please don't suggest me using of tables because I need to resolve my problem in the example above.

[image]

Comment: @Passerby Erik specifically stated no setting height and no tables. It's a difficult problem and it would be great to know the correct answer if there is one. I've never understood why 100% of a fluid height container can't work when the browser obviously does know what it is.

Comment: @guymid In CSS3 flexbox model you can do that more easily -- but flexbox support in the real world is messy. So yeah, you pointed out that this IS a difficult problem, and even with the no-table request (which is edit-added, not originally posted), table _may_ still be something eventually used. I can agree on kali's downvotes, but others are solutions; they may have flaw, but so does mine.

Comment: Guymid right. I think all web developers need that solution

Answer (score 2):

How about using [CSS tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#table-display) with your current markup:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/zgxXm/)**

### CSS

```
.container {
    display: table;
}

.column {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.cell {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 13px;    
}
.column:nth-child(2)
{
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.column:nth-child(2) .cell
{
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: This is nine solution but is it possible to prevent border: none?

Comment: try this - http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/zgxXm/1/ - I removed the border:none and instead - only set the border on the cell when necessary

Comment: Thanks for the solution but at now the following problem http://jsfiddle.net/zgxXm/3/

If content of center block is more then other ones. Is it possible to fix?

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your stylesheet:

```
.column:nth-child(2) .cell {
    padding-bottom: 18px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ANogImA/1/edit)

Comment: I can't use explicit values.

Comment: You said no height and no tables. Nothing about explicit values